# Can't generate F# interface lib for Orleans 3.0

Tags: f#, orleans

Can't build GrainLib (only interfaces) with Microsoft.Orleans.CodeGenerator.MSBuild 3.0.0 package

error:
Exc level 0: System.NotSupportedException: Projects of type .fsproj are not supported.

Is there workaround?

Upd

After Arshia001 explanation i return to finding errors in F# silo configuration and solved my problems by applying WithCodeGeneration instead WithReference and applying it for every assembly.

```
 .ConfigureApplicationParts(fun parts -> 
                    parts.AddApplicationPart((typeof<IMyGrain>).Assembly)
                            .WithCodeGeneration()
                          .AddApplicationPart((typeof<MyGrain>).Assembly)
                            .WithCodeGeneration() |> ignore)
```

it seems there are lot of issues with orleans documentation and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. I once started a discussion around adding first class F# support to Orleans, but it died down pretty quickly since nobody else seemed to be interested at the time.

You can always use runtime serializer generation. They do have an official F# sample too.

Comment: I used https://github.com/darting/orleans-fsharp as example they using 2.0.0 version. Can't make it working with orleans 3.x.x ver.